# Existe alguma norma, convenção ou prática que regre a utilização de domínios de servidores de arquivos estáticos?

Tags: servidor, dns, subdomínio

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

Cada cliente do meu serviço (SaaS) possui uma url personalizada. Para isso, criei um CNAME record `*.dominio.com` apontando para o meu servidor.

Ex.:
`empresa1.dominio.com`, `empresa2.dominio.com`, etc.

Para os arquivos estáticos, criei outro CNAME record apontando para o meu servidor de arquivos estáticos da seguinte forma: `*.static.dominio.com`, para conter a url da empresa.

Ex.:
`empresa1.static.dominio.com`, `empresa2.static.dominio.com`, etc.

Na prática, esses subdomínios apontam para o mesmo servidor de arquivos.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma convenção sobre este cenário, se seria uma prática ruim, se seria melhor deixar apenas `static.dominio.com`, ou se não faz diferença alguma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para HTTP, não faz diferença. O problema é quando envolve HTTPS, e a tendência é a Web migrar para HTTPS, então seria bom prever o layout de domínios para facilitar as coisas.

Um certificado HTTPs pode ser "wildcard", digamos *.empresa1.dominio.com, este certificado poderia ser usado no servidor estático static.empresa1.dominio.com, mas não se o servidor for empresa1.static.dominio.com. No último caso seria outro certificado e o browser pode reclamar porque o conteúdo está vindo de dois domínios com identidade (certificado) diferente.

O fato dos nomes apontarem para o mesmo servidor não é problema, já que servidores HTTPS também podem servir diferentes domínios num mesmo IP faz algum tempo (extensão SNI). Talvez no caso de HTTPS dever-se-ia usar um registro DNS A por cliente, e não CNAME porque CNAME realmente troca o nome por outro, e aí voltamos ao problema anterior.